# Best way of having Pathauto based off node title, but not tied to it?

Tags: path-aliases

Sorry for the poorly worded question, I'll try to better explain myself.

I'm swapping (not migrating) from WP to Drupal and I'm trying to replicate WP's URL feature. I want it to initially be based off the title of the node ("My First Blog Post" => "my-first-blog-post")

What I'm not wanting is Pathauto to be directly linked to the title, so I can update the title to something like "My First Blog Post (Updated 5/4/2017)" without having to worry about the URL changing. I want the URL to be easily editable if the need rises, I just don't want it tied to the title.

Would the best way just be to add an extra field, and manually enter a 'URL title' in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contributed module [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) will provide you a setting to set your own alias urls in the add content page.

Suppose you are adding a content of type basic page (using `node/add/page`), at the bottom there will be an *url path settings* tab where you can uncheck the 'Generate automatic URL alias' option and set your own path alias for the page.

Comment: I still want it automated for the most part becausse I want the content type to be automatic. I'm currently using `[node:content-type:name]/[node:title]`

Comment: You can do it by adding the pattern in the url aliases settings for the contents which is available in **admin/config/search/path/patterns**.

Comment: Yes, that's where I've done it. But if I follow your answer and uncheck the automatic URL alias, I won't get the functionality I want anymore

Comment: Not true @p3tch, that's exactly the functionality you've described as your requirement: set a pattern for a node type, create a node, that node now has an automatic initial alias based on the title. Then untick the "generate automatically" option, save the node, and pathauto will no longer affect it. That satisfies 1: _I want it to initially be based off the title of the node_, 2: _I can update the title to something like "My First Blog Post (Updated 5/4/2017)" without having to worry about the URL changing_ and 3: _I want the URL to be easily editable if the need rises_.

Comment: Oh, *then* uncheck it - I'm following now. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I think there's also a global pathauto setting to stop subsequent saves from updating the URL automatically, so you might be able to automate the whole process. Have a look through the pathauto settings pages, I think you'll find it in there @p3tch